# Use base64 encoded image in a PictureBox on acumatica report?

Tags: acumatica

I have a string that is a base64 encoded bitmap that I captured from a signature pad and stored in a custom table in the Acumatica database. I have a DAC for the table and I'm able to access it from the report designer.

The issue I'm having is how to get this base64 encoded image on to the report in Acumatica. There is a PictureBox control that would appear to be what I want except it doesn't seem to handle the encoded image data, only links to the database, an embeded file or URL.

I tried:

1. Setting the Source to "Database", the Mime Type to image/bmp and the
   value to the base64 encoded string field. This produced an error that the base64 wasn't a valid link. I expected that because it's not a link to a file stored in the database.
2. Setting the source to "External" and the value to the base64 also produced a similar error

Is there any way to handle this in Acumatica's report designer?

Because this is a hosted environemnt, I can't host a temp file so the best solution would be one that allowed the encoded bitmap from the database to be used inside the report somehow. However, any solution that gets the job done is welcome other than a local temp file as that's been ruled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save base64 string as file attachment in Acumatica. You could use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(<Base64String>)` to convert `base64 string` to `byte[]` and utilize `UploadFileMaintenance` Graph to save the image as file attachment.

```cs
//Graph for file management
UploadFileMaintenance upload = PXGraph.CreateInstance<UploadFileMaintenance>();

//Set filename
string fileName = string.Format(<FileName>, <FileExt>);
//Convert Base64 String to byte[]
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(<Base64String>);
//Create file info, you may check different overloads as per your need
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName, null, data);
upload.SaveFile(file, FileExistsAction.CreateVersion);

//To Attach file to Entity
PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(<PXCache>, <EntityData>, file.UID.Value);
```

You could refer [this KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25357224/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-an-acumatica-screen-through-http-virtual-path/25474174#25474174) for full file attachment Example. Once you have file as an attachment you should be able to use it in report by referring logo display in out-of-box Sales Order report (`SO641010`).

Comment: Thanks, this is basically all I could come up with as well. i was hoping to avoid using attachments but it seems like this might be the only solution.